# How to tokenize a string and assign tokens to column in Teradata?

Tags: string, teradata

I have multiple strings of the form {key1=value, key2=value2, key3=value3 ...} with a known set of keys. The key names are set and known, with only the values changing between records. I would like to tokenize the string with the space delimiter as my tokenizing character then strip off the key names and assign each one to a column in sequential order. Is this something I can do in-database in teradata 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with TD14 there's `NVP` to extract data from name-value-pairs, e.g.

```
NVP(col, 'key1', '{ ,\  }', '=')
```