# How to tokenize string by delimiters in teradata

Tags: string, teradata

I have a list of values stored as a string of the form [val1, val2, val3] is there a way to tokenize this string and stack the values in Teradata 15, in the style of [NVP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925691/how-to-tokenize-a-string-and-assign-tokens-to-column-in-teradata)? E.g.

```
select <magic function>(values,'[ , ]')
```

returns

```
col
------
Val1
Val2
Val3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mainly depends on the actual values and delimiters.

If any of the chars `',[] '` are treated as delimiters:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, '[val1, val2, val3]', ',[] ')
   RETURNS (keycol INT, tokennum INTEGER, token VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS dt
```

For multicolumn delimiters like yours `'['`, `']'`, `', '` probably better using REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TABLE (REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, '[val1, val2, val3]', '(\[|\]|, )', 'i')
   RETURNS (keycol INT, tokennum INTEGER, token VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS dt
```

Comment: If the source table has a key column for each string, how would I associate the two in the result table (e.g add a column 'ID' to the returns statement?)

Comment: @sakurashinken: The first parameter (I used a hard-coded **1**) is the  key column, either numeric or a string.